# Proving Lipschitz continuity (Real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A function $h : A → \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous if $\exists K$ s.t.

$$|h(x) - h(y)| \leq K \cdot |x - y|, \forall x, y \in A$$

Suppose that $I = [a, b]$ is a closed, bounded interval; and $g : I → \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $I$ and the function $G = Dg = g' : I → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Prove that $g$ is Lipschitz continuous on $I$.

Comment: Big hint: Mean+extreme value theorems.

Comment: Prove more (using the mean-value theorem as suggested by Jose27):  A differentiable function  $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz if and only if  $g'$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

On the intuitive side, consider this:

1. Lipschitz continuity essentially means that there's a bound on all possible difference quotients of a function, namely $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right\vert\leq K$
2. The mean value theorem guarantees that given a continuous function on a closed interval which is differentiable on its interior, any value that is attained as a difference quotient is also attained as a derivative.
3. If the derivative is continuous (or rather continuously extendable) on a compact interval, it is bounded, as all continous functions on compact intervals are.

These things should be enough to give you an idea why the thing you're proving is true, and how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, continuous functions in a closed, bounded interval attain maximum and minimum values. The derivative of $g$ is continuous, and so has a maximum value $m$.

Take any two points on the interval, say $x$ and $y$. By the intermediate value theorem,
$$
f(x) - f(y) = f'(\xi) (x - y)
$$
for some point $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. But we know that $f'(\xi) \leq m$. If you take the absolute value on both sides, you'll see that the Lipschitz constant you seek is $|m|$.